# Start program via batch the same as when starting via WindowsExplorer

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I start a game via batch file, then something is odd, I receive an error from the game about some graphic driver issues, but if I start the game by doubleclicking via WindowsExplorer then the game runs without any problems. So I guess there must be something different by starting it via batch.

Can you please explain how I start a game or program exactly the same like if I would doubleclick it in WindowsExplorer?

To be clear I add the whole batch script here and the file it loads:
the script takes an incomplete path to a file. In that file is the filename to an executable in the same folder and that executable should be executed.
Its for sure not solved the best way, but it works except for the executing part (it executes, but with error):

C:\Users\NiklasServer\Desktop\run_game\run_game.bat:

```
set "par1=%~1"

echo "%par1%">C:\Users\NiklasServer\Desktop\run_game\output.txt

:: executable relativ auslesen
set /p game_executable=<"\\Niklasynology/docker/emby%par1%"
echo "%game_executable%">C:\Users\NiklasServer\Desktop\run_game\output.txt

:: SETLOCAL
set gb_win_file=\\Niklasynology/docker/emby%par1%
FOR %%i IN ("%gb_win_file%") DO (
SET filedrive=%%~di
SET filepath=%%~pi
SET filename=%%~ni
SET fileextension=%%~xi
)

start "Emby Spiel" "%filedrive%%filepath%%game_executable%"

:: start "C:\Users\NiklasServer\Desktop\run_game\run_game.exe"
:: start "\\Niklasynology/docker/emby"
```

\Niklasynology\docker\emby\spiele\Windows\Age of Empires 2 - umbenannt\Age of Empires II.gbwin

```
EMPIRES2.EXE
```

Error after running game via batch:
translates to: Some graphics error occured - please make sure your system is compatible with DirectDraw
[image]

before starting game via WindowsExplorer:
[image]

after starting game via WindowsExplorer - game has correctly started:
[image]

Would be great if someone could help.
I am not very good at batch and therefore I guess it is some basic batch mistake like giving it admin-rights or something like that. Starting the batch script with admin rights didn't change anything.

PS: I tried these:

```
start "Emby Spiel" "%filedrive%%filepath%%game_executable%"
```

and

```
"%filedrive%%filepath%%game_executable%"
```

and

```
explorer.exe "%filedrive%%filepath%%game_executable%"
```

to start the game, result all in the same behaviour.

Comment: Type in the command prompt (explorer.exe "Path\To\App.exe")

Comment: Thank you @A7ec it is a great idea but sadly it didn't work. It results in the same behaviour

Comment: Try clicking on the program > properties > compatibility > then put windows xp in the compatibility mode section

Comment: compatiblity mode didn't change anything, but shoiuldn't be necessary either as it runs when starting from explorer.I tried this same routine with another game and it results in similar issues, it looks like the games don't have access to other files when started via batch

Comment: It's not clear what you are double-clicking in Explorer. If you are double-clicking a shortcut, then your batch file should launch the shortcut, not the executable directly.

Comment: @RaymondChen I doubleclick the executable, not a shortcut as can be seen in the second screenshot

Comment: Looks like your batch file does not set the current directory to the directory that holds the application.

Comment: @RaymondChen it seems like that is the issue! Thanks a lot! I used Pushd command to change directory and now it works! Best man!